# Complex pattern matching with strings

Tags: string, haskell

I have a list of strings that looks like this:

```
xs = ["xabbaua", "bbbaacv", "ggfeehhaa", "uyyttaccaa", "ibbatb"]
```

I would like to find only strings in the list which have and vocel followed by two b's followed by any character followed by a vowel. How are simple matches like this done in Haskell. Is there a better solution that regular expressions? Can anyone help me with an example? Thanks.

Comment: This is a perfect place for regex. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I looked at the various Regex modules, but the docs are really sparse and difficult to understand. How can I get a filter list with only matching words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the classic filter function in conjunction with any regexp library. Your pattern is simple enough that this would work with any regexp library :

```
filter (=~ "bb.[aeiuy]") xs
```

The confusing part of regexps in Haskell is that there is a very powerful generic API (in regex-base) to use them in the same way for all the specific libraries and the multiple result type you could wish for (Bool, String, Int...). For basic usages it should mostly work as you mean (tm). For your specific need, regex-posix should be sufficient (and come with the haskell platform so no need to install it normally). So don't forget to import it :

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
```

This [tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/) should show you the basics of the regex API if you have other needs, it is a bit out-dated now but the fundamentals remains the same, only details of regex-base have changed.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to build a small pattern-matching language and to embed it in Haskell.

In your example, a pattern is basically a list of character specifications. Let's define a type of **abstract characters** the values of which will serve as such specifications,

```
data AbsChar  =  Exactly Char | Vowel | Any
```

together with an "interpreter" that tells us whether a character matches a specification:

```
(=?)  ::  AbsChar -> Char -> Bool
Exactly c' =? c  =  c == c'
Vowel      =? c  =  c `elem` "aeiou"
Any        =? c  =  True
```

For example, `Vowel =? 'x'` will produce `False`, while `Vowel =? 'a'` will produce `True`.

Then, indeed, a pattern is just a list of abstract characters:

```
type Pattern  =  [AbsChar]
```

Next, we write a function that tests whether the **prefix** of a string matches a given pattern:

```
matchesPrefix  ::  Pattern -> String -> Bool
matchesPrefix []       _         =  True
matchesPrefix (a : as) (c : cs)  =  a =? c && matchesPrefix as cs
matchesPrefix _        _         =  False
```

For example:

```
> matchesPrefix [Vowel, Exactly 'v'] "eva"
True
> matchesPrefix [Vowel, Exactly 'v'] "era"
False
```

As we do not want to restrict ourselves to matching prefixes, but rather match anywhere within a word, our next function matches the prefixes of every **end segment** of a string:

```
containsMatch  ::  Pattern -> String -> Bool
containsMatch pat  =  any (matchesPrefix pat) . tails
```

It uses the function `tails` which can be found in the module `Data.List`, but which we can, to make this explanation self-contained, easily define ourselves as well:

```
tails  ::  [a] -> [[a]]
tails []          =  [[]]
tails l@(_ : xs)  =  l : tails xs
```

For example:

```
> tails "xabbaua"
["xabbaua","abbaua","bbaua","baua","aua","ua","a",""]
```

Now, finally, the function you were looking for, that selects all strings from a list that contain a matching segment, is written simply as:

```
select  ::  Pattern -> [String] -> [String]
select  =  filter . containsMatch
```

Let's test it on your example:

```
> let pat = [Vowel, Exactly 'b', Exactly 'b', Any, Vowel]
> select pat ["xabbaua", "bbbaacv", "ggfeehhaa", "uyyttaccaa", "ibbatb"]
["xabbaua"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try this function, although this may not be a best method:

```
elem' :: String -> String -> Bool
elem' p xs = any (p==) $ map (take $ length p) $ tails xs
```

Usage:

```
filter (elem' "bb") ["xxbbaua", "bbbaacv", "ggfeehhaa", "uyyttaccaa", "bbbaab"]
```

or

```
bbFilter = filter (elem' "bb")
```

Comment: This will not work. I need to match bbau but not bbat for example.

Comment: The parameter `p` is for the pattern. If you give "bbau", it will filter the strings which have "bbau".

Comment: Ok thanks, I see what you mean. I tried to provide a simplified example of my problem in the question, but it was too simplistic. I need to match on several possible characters at several positions. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're absolutely opposed to doing it with Regexs you could do it with just pattern matching and recursion, although it is ugly.

```
xs = ["xabbaua", "bbbaacv", "ggfeehhaa", "uyyttaccaa", "ibbatb"]

vowel = "aeiou"

filter' strs = filter matches strs

matches [] = False
matches str@(x:'b':'b':_:y:xs)
     | x `elem` vowel && y `elem` vowel = True
     | otherwise = matches $ tail str
matches (x:xs) = matches xs
```

Calling `filter' xs` will return `["xabbaua"]` which I believe is the required result.